# Python: reading a file and excluding lines with certain characters

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to write a function that opens a file and reads it, however I need it to ignore any lines that contain the character '-'

This is what I have so far:

```
def read_from_file(filename):
    with open('filename', 'r') as file:
        content = file.readlines()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gwang-Jin Kim and Heap Overflow answers are both 100% right, but, I always feel that using the tools that Python give you to be a plus one, so here is a solution using the built-in [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```py
list(filter(lambda line: "-" not in line, file.splitlines()))
```

---

```py
def read_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        content = filter(lambda line: "-" not in line, file.readlines())

    return list(content)
```

---

Here is a more verbose, yet more efficient solution:

```
def read_from_file(filename):

    content = []
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            if "-" not in line:
                content.append(line)

    return content
```

Comment: It is always interesting to show many ways to do one thing, but if OP is learning and can't do `if not "-" in line` yet then that sounds a bit overkill.

Comment: @Guimoute You are probably right, but that's why I +1 the other two answers in here.

Comment: would the above go on line 4 and then I could follow it with `print(content)?`

Comment: I edited my answer so you could see @TC1111. If you are planning to use the `filter()` function I would highly recommend taking a quick look at the link on the post to understand how it works. Always best to be informed what things are doing then just "it works!"

Answer (score 4):

Filter out character '-'-containing lines from your read-in lines:

```
filtered_lines = [x for x in content if '-' not in x]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd filter out while reading the file, not collect the unwanted lines in the first place.

```
def read_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        content = [line for line in file if '-' not in line]
```

Also note that the `'filename'` in your `open('filename', 'r')` is wrong and that the `'r'` is unnecessary, so I fixed/removed that.